# How to use mstats.kruskalwallis

Tags: python, scipy

I am try to to use the `mstats.kruskalwallis` with some groups of data stored in 'array', I try to put them into one list, but I found the `mstats.kruskalwallis` can not deal with the problem if the data in the list have different lengths.

For example

```
from scipy.stats import mstats
import numpy as np

a1=np.random.randn(10)
a2=np.random.randn(10)
a3=a1,a2
print(mstats.kruskalwallis(a1,a2))
print(mstats.kruskalwallis(a3))
```

The results are same as

```
KruskalResult(statistic=0.05142857142857338, pvalue=0.8205958397554376)
KruskalResult(statistic=0.05142857142857338, pvalue=0.8205958397554376)
```

However, if I set the two 'array' have different lengths, for example:

```
b1=np.random.randn(10)
b2=np.random.randn(12)
b3=b1,b2
print(mstats.kruskalwallis(b1,b2))
print(mstats.kruskalwallis(b3))
```

The results of first one is

```
KruskalResult(statistic=0.626086956521732, pvalue=0.4287942873854923)
```

And the second one is

```
ValueError: The input should be 2D
```

What can I do to deal with the error, if I have a b3 with several 'array'?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you need to add [argument unpacking operator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/) - `*`:

```
mstats.kruskalwallis(*b3))
```

The reason for this is the difference between a call of `kruskalwallis` function with **two** parameters vs. a call of the same function with **one** parameter that happens to be a tuple of two elements.

To turn this 2-tuple into two arguments of a function you need to use the asterisk - argument unpacking.